# iphone sdk: playing video from localhost?

Tags: iphone, video, sockets, localhost, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a server socket (on port 3490) in my app which has a video data - It runs on a different thread. Now I have a mpmovieplayercontroller and would like to read the data from the socket and play it. I'm not sure what url should I pass to it. I've tried file://localhost:3490
http://localhost:3490 
but this doesn't work. Please help

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your intentions, but why don't you just play the video from a file? If you're playing from localhost, surely the video is on your device? Why do you need to read it from a socket if its on localhost? Do you have a server running on the same device serving videos to a client app that is running on the same device???

Comment: Well actually we are working on video acceleration app. So right know I just want to find out how to communicate between a socket server and the movieController.

Comment: Basically we have some kind of a proxy server in the app so that the moviePlayer controller would think that he is requesting data from a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You say *server socket* but you don't mention what kind of protocol the server implements. Is it HTTP? If so then you will need to use a `http` URL.